# Reassignment to the same variable with the update() function in the lubridate package in R

Tags: r, lubridate

How can I re-assign the  new date/time to the same variable as shown in the following instruction:

```
mydate <- update(mydate, hours=11, minutes=30, seconds = 45)
```

Normally, `mydate` is kept unchanged How we can do it in only one line of code?

The following will work:

```
date2 <- pdate(mydate, hours=11, minutes=30, seconds = 45)
mydate <- date2
```

Comment: Isn't that being done in one line of code already? You can just get rid of the second line by changing the assignment to  `mydate <- pdate(mydate, hours=11, minutes=30, seconds = 45)` Please provide a reproducible example to show exactly what you want. `pdate` isn't a function from `lubridate` by the looks of it

Comment: @ChiNgo Also, I couldn't find `update` in `lubridate`.  There is a `stats::update` though.

Comment: @akrun `lubridate` has some internal `update` methods.  See, e.g., `lubridate:::update.POSIXlt`.